# How much is a transformer's secondary floating?

Tags: transformer, ground, isolation

Consider an isolation transformer with its secondary referenced to ground via a resistance R as in the following picture.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9iTRA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If R is infinite, the output voltage Output1-Output2 will float with respect to Ground. And if R is a short circuit, then that voltage is obviously referenced to ground.

However, what happens in between? Can the "floating offset" be quantified or at least bounded depending on that resistance?

Reason of the question: I'm wondering if a simple high resistance path to ground like this one could protect people from shocks (in series with the person's body) due to single point contact (as far as I'm aware, nothing protects against one finger on output1 and one finger on output2)... But letting it float is a danger as well. I am aware of RCDs, I'm just wondering if it's not a safe alternative, out of curiosity.

Comment: It looks like R is acting as a pull-down - unless you force Output 2 to be something else (externally?), it'll be 0V, and Output 1 is unsafe to touch. Isn't this worse than floating, where touching either output (but not both) is safe?

Comment: The bigger R will be, the smaller the current will be allowed to flow through a person's body if he/she touches the live wire as R will be in series with that person (only path round). But the bigger R will be, and the more the secondary will be allowed to float I assume (everything is continuous in reality), which can give quite a shock. However I'm not sure exactly what's the quantified relationship between R and floating offset.

Comment: Ah, I get it - as you increase R, Output 1 becomes safer to touch, and the limiting case of that is R = infinity, which we already know is safe to touch. Hmm. I think the amount of float depends on what else is in the air around your circuit.

Comment: I don't know about R=infinity is safe to touch, other people seem to say the shock can be quite hard because of static charge - it's only a lot safer than the other case. So that's what I'm asking, basically how can I come up with a quantified tradeoff, even if it's only in terms of orders of magnitude.

Comment: _"But letting it float is a danger as well."_ - Why?

Answer (score 1):

There will, in general, be a voltage on the output with respect to ground with a high value of R because of capacitive coupling and leakage between the windings.

Even a screened transformer (where the capacitive current is conducted out to earth) will have *some* voltage on each output with respect to ground. If the construction is symmetrical you might see half of the secondary voltage on each output terminal. Without the screen you might see that plus perhaps half the primary voltage.

I don't think there is a safety advantage in a resistor (it could be worse if the resistor can conduct harmful current from the secondary voltage) but it could be useful in low level circuits to keep the secondary from waggling around at 120VAC or whatever if no other ground exists in the circuit.

Comment: What I have seen is when you measure right to the transformers leads, ground not presents. But if you distribute this "floating output" by a cable -say- more than 30 meters, ground effect will be there! This is the reason that mains isolation transformer does not used (anymore) in gardens.

Answer (score 0):

I am in Canada, and we have 600V, 3 phase delta, ungrounded and floating.

If a phase gets accidentally grounded, nothing happens, but if another, different phase gets grounded, fuses will blow. These systems have a monitor for grounding faults.

Ungrounded systems can be safer, but only when they are monitored for faults. 
In older homes receptacles didn't have a ground. A ground-fault receptacle can be used in this case, and ground is not needed.

In solidly grounded systems, the problem is that grounding and bonding offers a good path for a fault current to harm. When I touch a stove, I have completed half of the circuit.

If I touch a live wire, I don't get a shock, but if at the same time I touch a stove, I get harmed.

Another problem is arc flash. It is when a live wire touches grounded surface. electric arc melts materials. The high temperature causes air to expand, and propel the melted materials at high speed.

Resistance grounding solves some of the problems, but it has to be monitored for faults. Resistance grounding reduces shock to ground by limiting current. It also eliminates arc faults to ground. In North America resistance grounding is not common.
Hospitals in some instances use isolating ungrounded transformers to isolate circuits.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late response but I wanted to give my opinion here.

I look at this situation in terms of Kirchoff's laws. You said you want to find a way to 'quantify' the in-between state when \$R_{isolation}\$ is neither a short nor a open circuit.

Consider the following circuit, which is essentially the same that you have except for a load that I added:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQeTLg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$V_x\$ and \$V_e\$ are referenced to ground. If a person touches \$\text{OUT}_1\$ with respect to ground, you can find (after applying Kirchoff's laws):

$$ V_e = -\frac{R_{Isolation}}{R_{Isolation}+R_{Human}}V_{in}$$

And

$$ V_x = V_{in}+V_e$$

As you said, if \$R_{Isolation}\$ is very large then (and with respect to \$R_Human\$):

$$ V_e \approx -V_{in}$$

And therefore \$V_x\approx0\$ which means almost no current or very small current run through the person.

If \$R_{Isolation}\$ is a short to gnd, then \$V_x\$ is the same as \$V_{in}\$. So the current through the person may be substantial (think \$V_{in}\$ is at main).

The in-between state can be quantified by the values of \$R_{Isolation}\$ and \$R_{Human}\$ because they determine how much potential will be across the person and therefore the current through.

The assumption is that earth ground is at zero potential which could very well be different. But at least, this gives some insight.